# How to open a folder from terminal on a Mac?

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

I want to open a folder that has all my resumes in it, how can I do that from the terminal?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

navigate to the dir and type

```
open .
```

Comment: "open _path to file_" will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

> cd dirname

to change the working directory. For example:

> cd resumes

will change to the "resumes" folder. You can then manipulate it with other commands (ls, mv, cp , rm, and many others).